# Use ffmpeg.c in my Android Application

Tags: java, c++, android, c, ffmpeg

I am building a video processing solution for use on Android phones. I have built FFmpeg for Android and have gotten a video to play using OpenGL. My next problem is being able to clip the files and save them to disk. I know that using FFmpeg from the command line this is easy. Do you guys think it would be possible for me to take the main() method in ffmpeg.c and change that into a function call and just pass the arguments to it, other than running it as a C program from the command line? I think this would require my app to be opensource but thats not a problem. Ok well any help or alternate ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that ffmpeg is GPL2. If you modify it and distribute the modification then you must distribute the source code of your modification. I am not a lawyer, but this can end up forcing you to distribute source to some/all of your app. http://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: I have thought about that, I do not know all of the details on it and definitely dont want to have any legal issues haha... I just want to play around with it and see what I can get it to do ya know, its just an independent project for now.

Comment: Hey Kieran I've a same issue , Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the NDK at all to link the methods to your android app?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I compiled everything with the NDK and am already using it to link to my app. I am hoping that I can basically just use ffmpeg.c from my current source file to do all the video processing for me...